# How can we get HHVM settings value using PHP?

Tags: php, hhvm

We can use `ini_get( 'upload_max_filesize' )` for getting ini values from PHP.

Is there a way like above for getting HHVM's ini values?

I am trying to get value from hhvm ini.

See this https://screencast.com/t/8vlLMsDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php echo ini_get('hhvm.server.upload.upload_max_file_size'); ?>`

The values on the left on your screenshot are the ini key names. Just copy / paste them in!